# In logstash how to get the date part to append in index name

Tags: ruby, filter, logstash

I am trying load the data into Elasticsearch using below logstash conf file. I have to create an index name with appending the date part of one of the column (dw_isnert_dt). When I am not aggregating this data to create map then it works fine but with aggregate it does not work as expected. So suppose dw_insert_dt value is "2021-04-27" then index name would be "test_index_2021_04_27". Please do help as I need this for my production deployment.

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521/ORCL"
        jdbc_user => "username"
        jdbc_password => "password"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "/home/logstash-6.2.4/jdbc_drivers/OJDBC-Full/ojdbc7.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        schedule => "35 4 * * *"
        statement_filepath =>"/home/logstash-6.2.4/queries/dummy.sql"
        }
}

filter {
        ruby {
        code => "event.set('dw_insert_dt_str', event.get('dw_insert_dt').time.localtime.strftime('%Y_%m_%d'))"
    }

    aggregate {
    task_id => "%{pkey}"
    code => "
        map['pkey']                 = event.get('pkey')
        map['name']                 = event.get('name')
        map['role']                 = event.get('role')
        map['dw_insert_dt']         = event.get('dw_insert_dt')

        map['CUST_ADDRESS'] ||= []
        customer_address_list = {'address_id' => event.get('address_id'), 'addr1' => event.get('addr1'),'city' => event.get('city') , 'state' => event.get('state')}
        if (event.get('address_id') != nil )
            if ! map['CUST_ADDRESS'].include?(customer_address_list)
            map['CUST_ADDRESS'] << customer_address_list
            end
        end

       event.cancel()
       "
       push_previous_map_as_event => true
       timeout => 20
     }
   }

output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "test_index_%{dw_insert_dt_str}"
        hosts => [ "host:port" ]
    }
}
```

Please do help at earliest.

Thanks,
Deepak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the push_previous_map_as_event option then the only fields that will exist on the event are the ones you added to the map. In this case you add [dw_insert_dt_str] to the original event, but you event.cancel that. You need to add it to the map.

You could copy it from the event

```
map['dw_insert_dt_str']         = event.get('dw_insert_dt_str')
```

or move the ruby code to the aggregate filter

```
map['dw_insert_dt_str']         = event.get('dw_insert_dt').time.localtime.strftime('%Y_%m_%d')
```

Comment: Do you mean I use as below. though i have used this inside aggregate function but got error as "ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action"

map['insert_dt_str']             = event.get('dw_insert_date').time.localtime.strftime('%Y_%m_%d'))

Comment: Updated to answer that.